# Wildfly 8.2.0 Doesn't redirect to https

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-8

I have enabled https changing standalone.xml as follows:

```
 <security-realms>

        <security-realm name="UndertowRealm">  
            <server-identities>  
                <ssl>  
                    <keystore path="./ed.keystore" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" keystore-password="secret" alias="ed" key-password="secret" />  
                </ssl>
            </server-identities>  
        </security-realm> 
        ...
```

and:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:1.2">
        <buffer-cache name="default"/>
        <server name="default-server">
            <http-listener  name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" />
            <https-listener name="https"   socket-binding="https" security-realm="UndertowRealm" />
```

Both the following links work:

- http://localhost:8080
- https://localhost:8443

the second actually is a secure connection.

Unfortunately, the first link doesn't redirect to the https protocol.

What have I missed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you add this in your web.xml

```
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <user-data-constraint>
      <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
  </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

This will allow the redirection for any URL.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that, I have it in my app. Tks.

Comment: @Fabrizio Is there any other security constraint in the web.xml file as described on this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27302201/redirect-every-http-request-to-https?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have only one security constraint in my app Apparently, clearing all the caches on the browser and some directories on wildfly (data,tmp) solved the problem.

Comment: I have tried all the above steps but still not able to redirect  http --> https

Comment: @PratikAnand Which version ?

Comment: wildfly-8.2.0.Final